# Get SQLite3 error message from error code

Tags: sqlite

There is a (potential) problem with using `sqlite3_errmsg()`:

> it might be the case that a second error occurs on a separate thread in between the time of the first error and the call to these interfaces

So if I already have a error code returned by some function, can I get the corresponding error message in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a public API wrapper for sqliteErrStr() that you can use

```
SQLITE_API const char *sqlite3_errstr(int rc);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function that does the job is

```
SQLITE_PRIVATE const char *sqlite3ErrStr(int);
```

but is declared as `PRIVATE` aka `static`.

In the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) they propose to lock the database connection and then read both the error code and the error message.

An alternative *easy* solution is to make the function public, if you have access to the source code.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen the suggestion in docs but hoped for a simpler way.